# I need larger image to get pulled from facebook when user signs up

Tags: python, django, facebook, twitter

When a user signs up to my site their facebook profile image automatically gets pulled and used as their profile image. The image is tiny so it looks pixelated. Is there any way to pull a larger version of the profile image? The same also happens for users who sign up using twitter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the different options on the graph api to get images of different sizes and shapes:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{{ user.uid }}/picture?type=small
http://graph.facebook.com/{{ user.uid }}/picture?type=normal
http://graph.facebook.com/{{ user.uid }}/picture?type=large
http://graph.facebook.com/{{ user.uid }}/picture?type=square
```

Unfortunately none of them are too large.  Getting the full size pictures is a bit more complicated.  You need to actually go in and get a list of the user's albums:
    https://graph.facebook.com/[uid]/albums?access_token=[AUTH_TOKEN]
For which you'll need the `user_photos` permission.  You'll then need to parse this result and look for an album with name `Profile Pictures` and type `profile`.  After that you can get the photos from this album via `https://graph.facebook.com/[ALBUM_ID]/photos?access_token=[AUTH_TOKEN]` and then parse the json result to get the first photo in full size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **width** and **height** options:

> http://graph.facebook.com/{{ user.uid }}/picture?width=xxx&height=xxx

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/picture#modifiers